# How to read Registry entries from disk archive?

Tags: windows-registry

My old PC (running Windows XP) had RAID controller failure on the motherboard, not worth fixing. Fortunately, I was able to extract and save all the disk files on an external 3 Terrabyte hard drive. How can I read the old XP Registry entries using my new Windows 10 laptop? I assume they are in some (hidden ?) file(s) on the external drive archive. Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 10):

The registry files, which are called "hives", are not hidden. They are the files-without-extensions in `\Windows\System32\config` . For example, the "system" hive (seen in regedit as `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\System` ) is `\Windows\System32\config\System` . And, each user's user profile hive is `ntuser.dat` in that user's "home directory", which in XP was `\Documents and settings\username` .

To read these, just run `regedit` and select either `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE` or `HKEY_USER` in the left pane. Then go to `File | Load hive` . Browse to where the old hive file is and select it. Then it will prompt for a key name. Make up a name that will be the "parent" key for everything in that hive. (Don't use something like `System` that's already there. You could use `old_system` though.) OK out and you will find your new parent key name under e.g. 'HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE' and the contents of the hive under there.

You don't need to worry about the `.sav`, etc., files that have the same base name. `regedit` will handle those for you.

File permissions and registry key permissions will apply, so if the keys you're trying to look at aren't readable by Everyone, you'll likely have to take ownership of them and set a new permissions list.

To unload the hive, select the hive's "parent" key in the left pane (like `old_system` in the above example) and use `File | Unload hive`.

Loading a hive is not persistent across boots, so all of these manually loaded hives will be automatically unloaded at shutdown and not reloaded again unless you go through this again. Loading a hive does take some pageable kernel space memory, but the size is rather small for modern systems, os there's no great harm if you forget to do the unload.

Answer (score 2):

#### How can I read the old XP Registry entries using my new Windows 10 laptop?

You can read the entries using "regedt32" > "File" > "Load Hive".

Note:

- You made need to take ownership of these files to read them. If so please see my answer ["I need to set the proper permission for this action"](https://superuser.com/a/949432/337631).

The registry files (hives) are located as follows:

> A registry hive is a group of keys, subkeys, and values in the
> registry that has a set of supporting files that contain backups of
> its data.
>
> The supporting files for all hives except `HKEY_CURRENT_USER` are in
> the `%SystemRoot%\System32\Config` folder on Windows NT 4.0, Windows
> 2000, Windows XP, Windows Server 2003, and Windows Vista.
>
> The supporting files for `HKEY_CURRENT_USER` are in the
> `%SystemRoot%\Profiles\Username` folder.
>
> The file name extensions of the files in these folders indicate the
> type of data that they contain. Also, the lack of an extension may
> sometimes indicate the type of data that they contain.
>
> ```
> Registry hive                 Supporting files
> HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SAM        Sam, Sam.log, Sam.sav
> HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Security   Security, Security.log, Security.sav
> HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software   Software, Software.log, Software.sav
> HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\System     System, System.alt, System.log, System.sav
> HKEY_CURRENT_CONFIG           System, System.alt, System.log, System.sav, Ntuser.dat, Ntuser.dat.log
> HKEY_USERS\DEFAULT            Default, Default.log, Default.sav
> ```

Source [Windows registry information for advanced users](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/troubleshoot/windows-server/performance/windows-registry-advanced-users)

Comment: I've submitted an edit to update the link to its [current address](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/troubleshoot/windows-server/performance/windows-registry-advanced-users). If you'd prefer an archive link of the original, see https://web.archive.org/web/20150418202843/https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/256986